# Paragraph-style for footnotes in ConTeXt

Tags: footnotes, context

Is there a way to have paragraph-style footnotes in ConTeXt, similar to what is provided by the `footmisc` package? E.g.:

```
This is some text^1. This is some
other^2 text. This is some more
text.
--------
1 This is a footnote 2. This is
another footnote. See how it
begins on the same line as the
first footnote?
```

Comment: The footnote mechanism has been "MkIVised" recently. It will be best if you ask this question on the ConTeXt mailing list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for `\setupnotation[alternative=serried]` (controls the number placement) combined with `\setupnote[paragraph=yes]` (removes the breaks).

```
\setuppapersize[A6,landscape]
\define[1]\footnotenumbercommand{#1.}

\setupnotation [footnote] [
  numbercommand=\footnotenumbercommand,
  alternative=serried,
]

\setupnote[footnote] [paragraph=yes,]

\starttext

Foo\footnote{This is a footnote.}
bar.\footnote{%
  This is another footnote. See how it begins on the same line as the
  first footnote?
}

\stoptext
```

[image: paragraph style footnotes]

Answer (score 0):

you can define the number of columns for the footnotes, eg:

```
\setupfootnotes[n=4]
```

Comment: I do not want columns. I would like for the information to appear in paragraph form.